# how to slide in content from outside the WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-animation

In my C# WPF Form I have buttons and textboxes. When I drag a button outside the bounds of the window it responds well. But when I drag the textboxes out of the window they cease to exist. After moving them out of bounds, I have a button that, when clicked, sets their position back into the window, though they don't appear to move back.

How can I prevent the textboxes from disappearing after moving them out of the window?

Comment: Can you post your code for better understanding the question?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to slide buttons and textboxes out of the window?

Comment: @MareInfinitus so that I can slide them in they have to be out first no?